# Export RSA ciphertext as a number in bash

Tags: bash, openssl, rsa

I am trying to encrypt a message using OpenSSL with RSA and print the result modulus 10. Everything works fine except from the modulus operation. It gives an invalid arithmetic operator error. I suspect that either `$(( ))` doesn't work as expected or the result of the encryption isn't in a suitable form to be converted to a number. Here's the code

```
#!/bin/bash

openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
cat plain.txt \
  | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.pem \
  > cipher.txt
cat  cipher.txt
res=$((cipher.txt)) % 10
echo $res
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Cyrus I have. But why doesn't this question meet the requirements? I practically posted the whole code so unless it's not minimal it does meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, as it currently stands, is ambiguous. This statement

```
res=$((cipher.txt)) % 10
```

does not make any sense. Syntax errors aside, you cannot just interpret an entire file as one huge integer and then perform a modulus operation on it. There is a limit on the integer size that Bash can handle.
One possibility, which may come close to what you want, would be to calculate several chunks of data and then print the result:

```
declare -i SIZE=1

while read -a d;do
    for ((i=1;i<${#d[@]};i++));do
        echo $((${d[$i]} % 10))
    done
done < <(od -t u$SIZE cipher.txt )
```

The above code will interpret each byte of `cipher.txt` as decimal number and perform a modulus calculation on it. If you change `SIZE=2` then it will interpret two bytes as one decimal number and so on.
This, however, will print several results to the screen.

Judging from your question you might actually just want to compute some kind of checksum. In this case `md5sum` or `shasum` might be of interest to you.

Without further clarification no more precise answer can be given.

Comment: Thanks to the magic of modular arithmetic, you can calculate the overall result from the chunks. Just add `result=0` before the loop, `result=$(( (${d[$i]} + (6*result)) % 10 ))` in the loop, and `$result` should have the right number at the end. Note that the `6` in that calculation is `(256**SIZE) % 10`, which happens to be 6 for any `SIZE` greater than zero.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: This comment really needs to be an answer.

Comment: I am not sure that reading each byte as a number will give what I want. For example, if we take that the plaintext = 1, n = 6 and e = 3 we get that the ciphertext = 1. So, 1 % 10 = 1. The problem is that during the encryption the algorithm doesn't read 1 as an int but as a text. So, now I want to do the opposite of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the *value* you wrote to `cipher.txt` in the arithmetic expression, along with the actual arithmetic operation.

```
IFS= read -r cipher < cipher.txt
res=$(( cipher % 10 ))
```

Comment: It didn't work. You were also missing a parenthese in the end.

Comment: What do you mean, "It didn't work"? Assuming `openssl` actually outputs something that `bash` *can* perform arithmetic on, this is the code that will do it.

Comment: I am expecting to see a number from 0 - 9. Instead, I'm seeing something like garbages and a syntax error: operand expected(error token is "and garbage again".

Comment: What ended up in `cipher.txt`, and what ended up in `cipher` when you read from the file? The second line is *absolutely* what you need for the computation, but I have no idea what you are starting.

Comment: I am starting with a number in plaintext and I want to end with a number in ciphertext mod 10. The problems is that the encryption hides the number in a non number formatting.